# Merging 2 columns into a third column and adding text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a range of last names and a range of first names 
and need to add CSWAH_
and need it to look like
CSWAH_LastName,FirstName
Last Names are between (A7,A26)
First Names (B7,B26) and need them to merge them into (C7,C26)

[image]

Comment: This is the last bit of a string of Macros Im trying to put together but cant figure out how

Comment: Why don't you simply use a formula? `="CSWAH_"&A7&", "&B7`. If you need help with VBA code, please edit your question and post the code that you need help with. Don't put that in a comment. Edit the question.

Comment: Trying to export into another program, formula can't transfer but command button macros can

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do this with a simple fomula like teylyn said, but if you realy want to do it with vba, this should work for your example:

```
Sub cobine()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 7 To 26
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "CSWAH_" & Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```